# Basic SharePoint Web Analytics

Tags: document-library, web-analytics

I'm looking for a count of all document library list items in all sites in a particular site collection to be retrieved through the OOTB web analytics page.

Note: This query must recursively search all sub folders within each document library also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Analytics is a pain to work with and create custom reports. Your request is a fairly simple search query, you should look that way.